# Ajax.BeginForm does not work in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, ajax.beginform

When I use Ajax.BeginForm with updateTargetId, it works fine in IE - replacing the html inside updateTargetId's tag. The same thing redirects the page to form's action. Does Ajax.BeginForm work in firefox?

Comment: I haven't got a chance to test this yet. Glad to know that it works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it absolutely does.  You probably have either poorly formed HTML or a javascript error that is preventing it from working properly.

If you still can't find it, post the rendered markup and we can look at it.

Comment: Yeah, it must be some unclosed tag for sure. it happens to me often